# How does Linux's sort command apply subsequent passes to data?

Tags: linux, sorting, command-line

There's an example in *A Practical Guide to Linux Commands, Editors, and Shell Programming* that looks like this.

You have a file, "fruit", that contains the following:

```
Pear
Pear
apple
pear
Apple
```

Executing this command:

```
sort -u -k 1f -k 1 fruit
```

Results in this output:

```
Apple
apple
Pear
pear
```

Why does this work?  If I execute only the first pass:

```
sort -u -k 1f fruit
```

This results in:

```
apple
Pear
```

The first pass appears to eliminate lines that somehow reappear on the second pass of the former example.  Also, since the first pass results in unique lines, I would expect the second pass not to happen at all.

Comment: `sort` is not a `bash` command; it is a separate command that you happen to be starting from `bash`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the clarification.  I fixed the title.

Answer (score 3):

By using secondary sorting key, you're telling sort "if the fields are the same, use this to compare them". So, `-k1f` sees `Apple` and `apple` as equal, so calls `-k1` to compare them. The result isn't "equal", so `-u` doesn't remove anything.

Comment: Why doesn't the second pass, `-k 1`, reorder `Apple apple` to `apple Apple`?

Comment: @Bryan: Weird, but that's what I get from `sort -k1f` or `sort -k1f -k1`, too.

Comment: @Bryan, whether upper- or lower-case comes first depends on your language's collation order. If you set `LC_COLLATE=C`, then it's ASCII order, and upper-case explicitly comes first (`A` is 65, whereas `a` is 97). If you don't set `LC_COLLATE`, it depends on your locale.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah, that explains a lot.  So with that said, does @choroba's answer imply that `-u` only applies during the final pass?

Comment: @Bryan, I'd consider it less ambiguous to say that `-u` only applies if all fields compared match.